# Add value from the previous row if condition is met and from the same row but different column otherwise

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to add a new column to a dataframe in R based on a condition on one of the columns. If the condition is met, I want to update the cell in the new column with the value in the previous row (same column). otherwise, I want to the use the value from the column which is used in the condition. Here is an example.

| Time | Lptr | Rptr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | -1 |
| 2 | -1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | -1 |
| 4 | -1 | 10 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 |

Now, I want to add a new column, called LAP based on the values in Lptr. If Lptr is equal to -1, I want to copy the LAP value from the previous row, otherwise LAP should be equal to Lptr. Here is what I want to get in the output.

| Time | Lptr | Rptr | LAP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | -1 | 0 |
| 2 | -1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | -1 | 2 |
| 4 | -1 | 10 | 2 |
| 5 | -1 | 5 | 2 |

I use the following which gives a strange output (at least I don't understand what is happening there).

```r
test$LAP <- ifelse(test$Lptr==-1, test$LAP[-1], test$Lptr)
```

Any help/pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may take help of `replace` and `fill`.

Change `Lptr` value to  `NA` value where `Lptr = -1` and `fill` the `NA` values with the previous non-NA value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test  <- test %>%
  mutate(LAP = replace(Lptr, Lptr == -1, NA)) %>%
  fill(LAP)

test
#  Time Lptr Rptr LAP
#1    1    0   -1   0
#2    2   -1    0   0
#3    3    2   -1   2
#4    4   -1   10   2
#5    5   -1    5   2
```

**data**

```
test <- structure(list(Time = 1:5, Lptr = c(0L, -1L, 2L, -1L, -1L), 
Rptr = c(-1L, 0L, -1L, 10L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice little idea. Since I didn't want to update the original columns, I did it a bit differently. `test  <- test %>%
  mutate(LAP = replace(Lptr, Lptr== -1, NA)) %>%
  fill(LAP)`. 

Just for understanding: How would I do this with indexing? The way I was doing it before?

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve your goal by (assuming the first `Lptr` is not `-1`):

```r
test$LAP <- test$Lptr
for (i in 1:length(test$LAP)) {
    if(test$LAP[i] == -1)
        test$LAP[i] <- test$LAP[i-1]
}
```

There are other ways of doing this. I felt this method would provide a clearer understanding.

Comment: You are right, this works for small data frames. But I have 5M records in my data frame and this one stuck forever.

Answer (score 1):

Using `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test %>%
    mutate(LAP = case_when(Lptr != -1 ~ Lptr)) %>%
     fill(LAP)
  Time Lptr Rptr LAP
1    1    0   -1   0
2    2   -1    0   0
3    3    2   -1   2
4    4   -1   10   2
5    5   -1    5   2
```

#### data

```
test <- structure(list(Time = 1:5, Lptr = c(0L, -1L, 2L, -1L, -1L), 
Rptr = c(-1L, 0L, -1L, 10L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```